How do I update the version of JetBrains running on a remote server?
I'm using PyCharm with JetBrains Gateway to work on a remote EC2 instance. I updated my local version of PyCharm but then discovered that the version running on the remote server didn't update. How do I update it?

I had to Google a bit to find an answer to this:
You need to delete the existing IDE backend and create a new one.

In the project-selection window, click the gear icon.




Click "Manage IDE Backends".




Click the "X" icon to remove the backend that needs to get updated.




Click the 'Add Project' button.




Navigate to the directory with your code and click Download IDE and Connect.






If you just click the 3 dots next to your project, you can install a new IDE backend without removing the old one. That way, you don't have to set up you project again. You can remove the old IDE backend afterwards as described above.
